# Missing resource tf

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install RGB-D SLAM on Ubuntu 12.04 as per these instructions
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam#RGB-D_SLAM_for_Non-ROS_Users

However, when I get to the

```
rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg
```

part, I receive this error:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rgbdslam: Missing resource tf
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/paul/ros
ROS path [2]=/home/paul/ros
```

I know that the package tf is here
http://ros.org/wiki/tf
but I don't know how to install it.

How do I go about installing this package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47285/missing-resource-tf/) by [Twenty](https://answers.ros.org/users/3515/twenty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-11-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [P.Naughton](https://answers.ros.org/users/2954/p.naughton/) on 2012-11-02**:
I believe it is in the full desktop install of ROS. Is this how you installed ROS? For me tf is located at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf, I would check if that is the case for you. If it is, add /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks to your package path and rosdep should be able to find it

**Comment by [Twenty](https://answers.ros.org/users/3515/twenty/) on 2012-11-04**:
Oh yeah, I can find tf under /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf, but how do I go about adding it to the package path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out! I used:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/paul/ros:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/
```

---

Originally posted by [Twenty](https://answers.ros.org/users/3515/twenty/) with karma: 36 on 2012-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-04**:
Managing ROS_PACKAGE_PATH manually is not recommended. You should instead use rosws. Have a look at [this page](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays).

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-04**:
At the very least, you should only add to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash first.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-11-06**:
You probably skipped the step ". ~/.bashrc" in the manual.